SOQL 101 on Invocable Apex Class from Flow Trigger
I'm fully aware that I'm not even slightly an Apex Developer, and have attempted to cobble this together from other sample code.
Problem Statement:
I'm running a custom flow that is deleting email messages due to storage issues from them, and cloning them back into standard tasks (you'll notice most all EmailMessage records have an ActivityId field, this is what I'm cloning).  The "Cloning" process is really to just query the paired activity record that points to the Email message, and re-insert it, since when you delete the email message Salesforce cascade-deletes the task that points to the email message.
Because Tasks get archived, the normal "Get" element in flows fails to return anything querying for that ActivityId on an email message, so I tried an invocable apex method.
This code works correctly on small batch sizes, but anything at the normal 200 transaction size limit fails due to SOQL 101 or 201 in bulk.  I'm confident the issue is exclusively tied to this invocable APEX class, because I have no issues doing the same flow in bulk if I skip this apex, and we are extremely clean on SOQL in general in our flow triggers.
I was expecting the flow to iterate the elements prior to the Apex Action and build the set of task Ids to pass into this apex method, and then a single query to be run and return the complete list of tasks to the flow, but it seems that its running the query for each input task Id string.
Apex Class
public class InvocableQueryArchivedTask {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Get Archived Task' description='Returns Full Task Record' category='Task')
  public static List<Task> getArchivedTask(List<ID> ids) {

    List<String> fields = new List<String>(Task.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
    String soql = ''
        + ' select ' + String.join(fields, ',')
        + ' from Task'
        + ' where Id in :ids AND IsDeleted = FALSE ALL ROWS';
    List<Task> tasks = database.query(soql);
    return tasks;
  }
}

Flow Pictures




Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange.  Can you [edit] your post to clarify "deleting email messages ... and cloning them back into standard tasks"?  How are you copying an emailMessage into a new Task record?

How does the Email Message query look like?

@DavidCheng I updated.  The Clone is actually of the task record that SFDC creates for most all email messages that points to the email message.  When you delete the email message salesforce automatically deletes the task record they auto create.  So my approach here (that is working on low batch sizes) is to query that existing task, and just  re-insert it before deleting the email message, since I know Salesforce will delete the task that points to the email message

@zanstaszek9 I added a picture of the email query, its just a standard flow "get record" element that should automatically bulk itself as far as I've seen in the past.

are you sure that the automation behind Clone Task (insert) element is bulkified (other triggers); I also see a Loop CDLs in the flow -- could your SOQL issue be here?

Do you want to run this only once? or once in a while (2-3 times a year)? or once every month? or once every night? If you answered yes for any of these, I think, the fastest resolution would be to write a Batch Apex and schedule it. Besides, how are you deleting all of the emails?

@cropredy yes I'm certain its bulkified.  I regularly run mass inserts / updates without bypassing any triggers on tasks & email messages on Batch = 10000k.  The CDL loop has no queries, just assignments to set the the new task Id for the CDL, and to add the variable to an insert collection that gets processed at the very end of the flow.

@prem22 for now I want to run this at my discretion to trim down the >50% data storage consumed by Email Messages, focusing on oldest first, but eventually the goal is to turn this into an automated nightly job that trims off everything past some date threshold (e.g. older than 3 years).  The Delete action is a standard flow "delete" element.  Doing this deletes both the emailmessage, plus the task that is referenced in the "ActivityId" field on the email message.  Its that task that I'm querying here to then re-insert.

I'd recommend making a case to SF support unfortunately. For me, your Flow looks perfectly fine to be bulkified, and the fact that this thread haven't got any reasonable answer yet means that we do not know what is going on here.

This might be a shot in the dark, but have you tried modifying the invocable apex to accept a list of EmailMessage records and getting the IDs that you need for the query in your apex? Might not change anything but I've seen different behavior using sObjects compared to ID being passed to methods in the past.
